# How do I mark a method as not-threadsafe?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

Every so often I hit upon this problem and ignore it, but it started gnawing at me today.

```
private readonly object _syncRoot = new object();

private List<int> NonconcurrentObject { get; } = new List<int>();

public void Fiddle()
{
    lock (_syncRoot)
    {
        // ...some code...
        NonconcurrentObject.Add(1);
        Iddle();
    }
}

public void Twiddle()
{
    lock (_syncRoot)
    {
        // ...some different code...
        NonconcurrentObject.Add(2);
        Iddle();
    }
}

private void Iddle()
{
    // NOT THREADSAFE! DO NOT CALL THIS WITHOUT LOCKING ON _syncRoot
    // ......lots of code......
    NonconcurrentObject.Add(3);
}
```

I have multiple public methods of a class with some code that is not inherently threadsafe (the `List` above is a trivial example). I want to use helper methods for the code shared between them (as anyone would), but in splitting off the shared code I'm faced with a dilemma: do I use recursive locking in the helper methods or not? If I do, my code is wasteful and possibly less performant. If I don't (as above), the helper method is no longer threadsafe and open to a nasty race condition if called by some other method in the future.

How can I (elegantly and robustly) signal that a method isn't threadsafe?

Comment: You could use a custom attribute and a Roslyn Analyzer, but that may be overkill depending upon the scenario.

Comment: @yaakov: I'd love to see that answer.

Comment: Your example is not correct though. How come one function is not thread-safe and other functions are thread safe though those are dealing with same object.

Comment: XY problem.  Just use a _thread-safe_ collection

Comment: @MickyD using a thread-safe collection is only viable in trivial cases where the internal state of the collection is the only shared state that you have to protect. Because that's all that a thread-safe collection can guarantee: the integrity of it's internal state. When you have to do anything complex you are usually forced to do manual synchronization, because there is additional shared state that needs protection.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias OP's code is _"trivial"_.  All he is protecting is a .NET 1-style non-thread-safe collection.

Comment: @MickyD some comments indicate that OP's code is not trivial: `// ...some code...`, `// ...some different code...`. These are inside the protected regions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use doc comments.

```
///<remarks>not thread safe</remarks>
```

Comment: You know what. This is the answer. I'm being absolutely ridiculous here.

Comment: I do like this answer a bit more because creating an attribute to mark a method would convey to me some soft of behavior associated with that attribute. MSDN provides documentation that a certain class is thread safe or isn't. Documentation all the way.

Answer (score 1):

You could use custom attributes to mark methods that are not thread safe.

The advantage over comments is that it gives you options for further processing (via reflection) if you wish to do so at a later date.

```
public class NotThreadSafe : Attribute
{
    //...
}

public class MyClass
{
    [NotThreadSafe]
    public void MyMethod()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: To me this approach would convey a behavior associated with marking the method with an attribute because its compiled. A better approach is to document it with comments and XML style comments the better for public APIs.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the `_Unsafe` suffix to your utility methods that are not protected with locks.

**Advantages:** It reminds you that you are doing dangerous things, and so that you must be extra careful. A small mistake could cost you days of debugging in the future.

**Disadvantages:** Not very pretty, and can be confused with the [`unsafe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/unsafe) keyword.

```
private void Iddle_Unsafe()
{
    NonconcurrentObject.Add(3);
}

public void Twiddle()
{
    lock (_syncRoot)
    {
        NonconcurrentObject.Add(2);
        Iddle_Unsafe();
    }
}
```